# Calling a function inside a foreach goes to a different place than outside the foreach?

Tags: php, push-notification, web-push

Wow talk about a mind bender. Ok, so whenever I run this

```
<?php

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;

$public_key = "PUBLIC_KEY_REDACTED";
$private_key = "PRIVATE_KEY_REDACTED";

$auth = array(
    'VAPID' => array(
        'subject' => 'https://github.com/Minishlink/web-push-php-example/',
        'publicKey' => $public_key, // don't forget that your public key also lives in app.js
        'privateKey' => $private_key, // in the real world, this would be in a secret file
    )
);

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
file_put_contents("notification_subscription_info.txt", file_get_contents("php://input"));
try {
    $subscription = Subscription::create(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true));
    $notification = [
        'subscription' => Subscription::create([ // this is the structure for the working draft from october 2018 (https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-push-api-20181026/)
            "endpoint" => "{$json->endpoint}",
            "keys" => [
                'p256dh' => "{$json->keys->p256dh}",
                'auth' => "{$json->keys->auth}"
            ],
        ]),
        'payload' => 'Hello!',
        ];

    $webPush = new Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush($auth);

    $webPush->sendNotification(
        $subscription,
        $notification['payload'] // optional (defaults null)
    );
    //version 1 (outside the foreach)
    $webPush->flush();

    //version 2 (inside the foreach)
    foreach($webPush->flush() as $report) { } //This can be empty
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I get very weird behavior in my debugger phpstorm. If I run it with version 1 then I get no push notification and it calls a __destruct method.

If I run version 2 however I get normal behavior and the push notification sends successfully. It appears as if by merely being inside the foreach it changes the flow of the program. I have no idea why this would be and I'm left scratching my head. Does anyone know what is happening?

Edit: I was mistaken about the __destruct method. That's being called because it's the end of the function. In the debugger it's skipping over the flush() call as though it's a literal value. So if I do `$report = $webPush->flush();` it will set $report without ever even calling the flush() function (at least that's what it seems like). I even have a breakpoint at the beginning of the flush() function and it isn't hitting it.

Comment: It would seem you need multiple levels of flushing. Presumably `while ($webPush->flush()) {}` would also work (and look more intuitive).

Comment: This is exactly what I thought so I had it run in a loop 10000 times and I still got the same behavior. It seems to only work in the foreach.